# Process a list of items from multiple drives

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples that looks like the image below. I am passing the list into a python function to process each item in the list. I need to access multiple system drives to process the list. My current program opens the drive each time. This is inefficient. I want to open the drive only if the current item in the list is from a different drive from the last item processed.

```
(1, 18911232, 'af1a83d6b18bf3e065be82cf44246037', 'D')
(2, 18911744, 'd5cedca078545cbcb0b2a9b514f9b92d', 'D')
(3, 18912256, '457ee2f5dc6f95b09599fc3f479878b6', 'D')
(4, 27076608, '8fb1ee8d6d8df00e53055e0eb48ef2e5', 'E')
(5, 27077120, 'a9ea5ccfebe4d6b3ecdd429518fff688', 'E')
(6, 27077632, 'ff722e8bb3c731ece625f882a090f100', 'E')
(7, 19604324352, 'd1fd613c04c983d73d79027f2a3425f9', 'C')
(8, 19604324864, '6f51f480b2ad733f20a54c8d3f5dd38c', 'C')
(9, 19604325376, '066fdaddf301b83402934e5783a3eec3', 'C')
```

```
def check(oldList):
    newList = []#To hold processed list
    try:
        for item in oldList:
            drive = item[3]
            volume = r"\\." + '\\'+ drive + ':' #Constructing string to open the drive.                  
            with open(volume, 'rb') as disk: #Open drive
                disk.seek(item[2])#Move to sector address on disk
                sector_data = disk.read(512) #Read sector data (512 bytes)
                sectorHash = md5HashFunc(sector_data)#Hash sector data
                if sectorHash==item[3]:  
                    pass #If data matches, do nothing - sector still intact
                else:
                    newList.append(item[1])
    except Exception as err:
        logging.exception(err)
        logging.info('=======================================================\n')
        notificationMessage('An error occured and has been logged, see log for details.')
    return newList #Return new list.
```

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of text.

Answer (score 0):

> want to open the drive only if the current item in the list is from a different drive from the last item processed

Store the last seen drive, then check if it changes as you loop

For example

```
drive = None
prevDrive = None
disk = None
for item in oldList:
    drive = item[3]
    if drive != prevDrive
        volume = r"\\." + '\\'+ drive + ':'
        if disk is not None:  # if previously assigned
            disk.close()
        disk = open(volume, 'rb')
    
    # do work
    disk.seek(item[2])

    prevDrive = drive
if disk is not None:
    disk.close()
```

This will only work for a relatively sorted list of drives, though.

The alternative is to store a dictionary of file handles

```
drive_map = {item[3]: open(r"\\." + '\\'+ item[3] + ':', 'rb') for item in oldList}
for item in oldList:
    disk = drive_map[item[3]]
    # do work
    disk.seek(item[2])
     
# make sure to close all the files when done
for _, f in drive_map.items():
    f.close()
```

---

Also not sure why you're checking the sector hash is equal to the drive value since hashes generally are not a single character